# Ember not generating model files

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to use the cli to generate model files but no files get generated. 
I run:

```
ember generate model blurbs
```

and it returns these two lines without any mention of actual files being generated (like app/models/blurbs.js)

```
installing model
installing model-test
```

I was able to generate my routes (ember g route blurb) correctly before but for models it lists no files and none are generated either.

This is my setup:

```
ember-cli: 3.11.0
ember-data: 3.11.2
node: 12.6.0
os: win32 x64
```

Comment: what version of `ember-data` are you using?

Comment: You might want to ask on the [Ember Discord Community](https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS)

Comment: @surreal_sai: I updated the question, it's version 3.11.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in Ember 3.11.x:

You can read about it here: https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/07/15/ember-3-11-released.html (Search for "Important Note")

For now, I recommend downgrading to Ember Data 3.10.

The bug has been fixed [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/6241), and should be in a future version of Ember Data, but the fix has not been backported to 3.11.

Update: Fixed in Ember Data 3.11.4

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. The PR linked in your post is about the `attr` decorator.

Comment: Should be fixed in Ember Data `v3.11.3`, which was released a few hours ago.

Comment: Actually fixed in v3.11.4